# What was the filming technique used to film "Jim's Ride"?

Tags: film-techniques, the-man-from-snowy-river

In [*The Man from Snowy River*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084296/), the movie's most famous scene portrays Jim Craig chasing down the mob of brumbies to retrieve the prize colt for his boss.

At about 1:55 into this clip, we are shown the mob of horses from the ground.  There are other movies that I have seen shots like this as well involving running horses.

**How are scenes like this filmed?**  It appears that the horses are running directly over the camera.  **Is there a name for this particular film technique?**

Comment: If you look closely, one of the horses bumps the camera and it moves right in the middle of that shot!

Comment: @user1118321 Oh, cool!  You're right!  So, they must have had a regular camera that was protected somehow I'm guessing.

Answer (score 5):

### "*Worm's eye view*" or just "*ultra low angle*".

[**VideoMaker.com**](https://www.videomaker.com/article/c10/1403-camera-work-shot-language)

> Whatever you call it, a worm's-eye angle is very useful for dynamic action (especially in combination with a wide-angle lens). Shooting the buffalo hunt in Dances with Wolves, for example, the **cinematographer created worm's-eye shots by burying a camera in a pit** and having the great beasts thunder directly over it.

With advances in miniaturisation and digital cameras, it is now possible to just bury a very small high resolution "lipstick" camera and forgo the requirement to dig a pit to hold the previously very large camera (and operator).

The same is true often when you see a motor vehicle pass over your viewpoint.

Comment: Yeah, but this movie is from the early 80's.  Was it still shot with the "lipstick" camera back then?   Is there anything stating that this particular scene was shot just like Dances with Wolves?

Comment: No but that wasn't the question...the question was about the **technique**. I'll have a look though.

Comment: I know that wasn't the question.  I was just asking about the paragraph in your answer.